# Postgres DB, how to only get one result

Tags: timestamp, postgresql-9.6

to keep it simple, this is what the db looks like:

```
state | name1 | name2 | timestamp
  2   | user1 | set1  | 2020-05-27 16:20:00
  6   | user1 | set1  | 2020-05-27 16:19:00
  8   | user2 | set1  | 2020-05-27 16:10:00
  2   | user2 | set1  | 2020-05-27 16:00:00
  2   | user3 | set1  | 2020-05-27 16:30:00
  2   | user4 | set2  | 2020-05-27 16:35:00
```

Explanation:

If the state is 2, the the user is logged in on the set given in "name2" at the given "timestamp".

If the state is 6 or 8 the user logged out from the set.
Now it's possible that a user logged in and out several times a day.
But i need to figure out which user is logged in now.

UPDATE: There can be more than one user logged in at the same time on one set.
I updated the table.

To make it clear, in this example i need the following output:

```
state | name1 | name2 | timestamp
  2   | user1 | set1  | 2020-05-27 16:20:00
  2   | user3 | set1  | 2020-05-27 16:30:00
```

Any hints how i could get it?
I am working two days now on this topic... asked google, came here, but it doesn't help me much.

This is not working for me because i get all users, doesn't matter if they latest logged in or logged out...

```
select  state,
        name1,
        name2,
        timestamp
from db1
where name2 = 'set1' AND timestamp >= current_date
order by timestamp desc,state,name1 limit 5;
```

Kind regards
JP

Comment: Thank  you, i am new to stackoverflow, so thankful for every advice.

Comment: i am working on that comment, to get it in fomat, sry

Comment: Again: do **not** put it into a comment. Add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now my colleague and I found the solution:

```
SELECT a1.name1 FROM db1 AS a1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS t_max, name1 from db1
where name2 = 'set1'
AND timestamp >= current_date
GROUP BY name1) AS a2
ON a1.timestamp = a2.t_max AND a1.name1 = a2.name1
WHERE a1.state = 2
GROUP BY a1.name1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `state = 2` to your `where` clause and setting `limit 1`
e.g.:

```
select  state,
        name1,
        name2,
        timestamp
from db1
where name2 = 'set1' AND timestamp >= current_date AND state = '2'
order by timestamp desc limit 1;
```

I also don't think you need more sorting than descending timestamp as the above query only returns logins to set1

Reference: [www.postgresqltutorial.com](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-limit/)

**N.B.** This will actually give you the last user to log on to set1; they could have logged off since.

Really you want to check the latest activity for set1 and only return it if it is 2.

Maybe someone else can improve my answer, but I have got you further

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but as shown in the table, it is possible that not only one user logged in to one set.
In the Table, user1 and user3 are logged in to set1 (state = 2).
But if i only search for state = 2 it is possible that i also get entries of users which already logged out...

Comment: Oh sorry i had a bad example in the table. So to make it clear, it is possible that more than one user is logged in to a set and i want all users which are logged in at the moment.